# Internet explorer cursor "point" bottom left of the image

Tags: html, css, cursor

I want to have an individual cursor on my [homepage](http://www.castlenightmare.bplaced.com/). For Internet Explorer i need the special file format .cur - after 2 days searching i found this. Now it also works in ie.

**But:** When you go over a link, (right the menue), you will notice that the point of the cursor which is actual the "pointing point" (the point of the image which is deciding a selection) is not like usual in the top left corner, but in the **bottom** left corner.

Im testing it with ie10. With the standart cursors all is ok, but not with the .cur file. 
So, whats wrong there? Or is my .cur file corrupt??

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0):

No, the cursor file is perfectly fine, that how normal cursor works. even in default cursor (like in stack overflow) you can try press add button or link with the bottom of the cursor and it wont work, only the corner activate the cursor sensitivity.

However, using default cursor is recommended, it making the website more mature or in other words less childish.

Comment: I think you didnt undeestand it right... i know that the corner is importnant, bzt usually its the top left corner. And its my thing to use a custom cursor on my homepage.